# Wordpress stored procedure

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress database development and I want to know how can I use stored procedure to select data from MySQL database. I know ordinarily I would use a line of code like this to select data from a database:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name FROM cust_users WHERE id = 1 ");
```

My question is, instead of writing `SELECT name FROM cust_users WHERE id = 1`, which code should I use, supposing I already have a stored procedure created.  It will de much help if you provide example. Thanks.

Comment: look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106509/how-call-stored-procedure-in-wordpress