# How call stored procedure in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to call a MySql store procedure which have made in wordpress database before. But It always returns an empty array. Is something wrong with my code? Running this code in MySql prompt show rows correctly.

```
public static function get_job_list($job_title = '', $qualify = '',$id = ''){
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
        $query = "SET @id='{$id}'; SET @job_title='{$job_title}'; SET @qualify='{$qualify}'; 
                        CALL `sp_job_list`(@id, @job_title, @qualify);";
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Try to make query with `prepare` method -- refer -- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Comment: Not works, yet empty array!

Comment: Do You have same `sql` error ? check `die(mysql_error())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when I put some other statement before call(or any other statement) always first statement which is `SET @id='{$id}'` will run and it return empty array. I should put only one query into my query!! something like this:

```
query = "CALL 'sp_job_list'('{$id}', '{$job_title}', '{$qualify}');";
```